# Is there a div() function in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm talking about the `div(X,Y)` function in C which returns the number of times X is reduced by Y

if you're confused, I'm talking about this:

> div(30,5) returns 6 (30 is reduced 6 times by 5)
>   div(34,7) returns 4 (you can reduce 30 by 7 four times, leaving 6 behind)

Is there such a function?

Comment: Cute. I always did integer math in C and it "worked for me", but now I wonder how it's really defined in the specification... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is, although creating your own is rather simple:

```
function div(a:Number,b:Number):Number
{
    return Math.floor(a/b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You have to divide num1 / num2 and use `Math.floor` to round it down to the closest integer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function div(n,d)
{
    var q=Math.floor(n/d);
    var r = n % d==0?0:(n-q*d);
    var div_t = {quot:q,rem:r};
    return div_t;
}
trace(div(34,7).quot+"___"+div(34,7).rem);
```